# mean.io cronjob | How to access server-side controllers directly?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean.io

How can I run some server-side script from cronjob/command-line? This script should be inaccessible from client-side.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [node-schedule](https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule):

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){
    console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

or [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron): (currently showing build errors)

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function(){
    console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, "America/Los_Angeles");
```

Mean.io doesn't explicitly name them in package.json so you will probably have to install one of them.